# How to find newest object in each document in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have Mongo documents in this form:

```
{
   _id: 'id',
   name: 'name',
   versions: {'2': {value: 1},
              '1': {value: 2},
              ...
   },
   lastVersion: 'lastVersionKey'
}
```

What I want to do is finding documents whose ***value*** in ***lastVersionKey*** equals to ***arbitraryValue***. How should I go for it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That isn't a good model. You can't reference a field from the value of another in either find or update operations. Perhaps presenting your use case for why you want to do this would be a better question to ask. If we know your reasons, then we can propose solutions.

Comment: I want to store nodes of a tree in db. Some fields of nodes (those placed in versions) can be changed during the time, so it makes different versions of that node. However, when I want to represent the node I should retrieve the last version.

Comment: It's your question that needs editing. Present your case. But I've already told you this schema will not work. So consider that.

Comment: If you're trying to store an audit, in Mongo, either move the audit data to another document and only store the current, or store the "current" explicitly in one field and store the audit in another field.  Don't store "pointers" as it makes common queries unnecessarily challenging. You can always merge the current and audit on the client. You can also duplicate the current and audit data if necessary.